# onClick to change the route by a condition of the array instead of repeating similar code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to coding and want to use React to build my portfolio website.
I'm now stuck in some route change problems but I don't want to use React Router in this stage. I use the traditional way to do this.

I crate some components and an array file to list the projects I want to put into. Here is what I intend to work like:

- component(a): ProjectList.
  This is the component to list all of the projects I made by using array.map to render the Card component.
- component(b): Card.
  This is the component to simply display the name, picture, and brief of each project. I want to set onClick in the picture to navigate to the main page of the project.
- component(c): Main.
  This is the component to show details of each project.

Here is my code

> ProjectList (component a)

```
const ProjectList = ({ projects, routeChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
      </div>
      <Container >
        <Row>
            {
              projects.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                  <Col xs={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
                    <Card 
                    key={projects[i].id}
                    id={projects[i].id} 
                    name={projects[i].name} 
                    subtitle={projects[i].subtitle} 
                    brief={projects[i].brief}
                    description={projects[i].description}
                    projects={projects}
                    routeChange={routeChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                );
              })
            }
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );  
}
```

> Card (component b)

```
const Card = ({ id, name, subtitle, brief, routeChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img alt='logo' src={test} onClick={() => routeChange(name)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>{id}</h1>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>{subtitle}</p>
          <p>{brief}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Main (component c)

```
const Main = ({ name, description }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </div>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} xl={6}>
            <img alt='project-view' src={test} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <p>{description}</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then here is the part of App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      route: 'home',      //default
    }
  };

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
   this.setState({ route: route })
  };

  render() {
    const { route } = this.state;    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { 
          route === 'home' ? (      //this nav to home page
            <div>
              <Dropdown routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Home routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            </div>)
          : route === 'projects' ? (     //this nav to project list
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <ProjectList projects={projects} routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            </div>)
        : route === projects[0].name ? (     //this nav to the first project page on the projects array
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Main name={projects[0].name} description={projects[0].description} />
            </div>)
          : route === projects[1].name ? (
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Main name={projects[1].name} description={projects[1].description} />
            </div>)
          : route === projects[2].name ? (
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Main name={projects[2].name} description={projects[2].description} />
            </div>)
          : route === projects[3].name ? (
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Main name={projects[3].name} description={projects[3].description} />
            </div>)
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It works but as you can see, I repeat similar code so many times in App.js. How can I change it concisely instead of repeating code?

I tried to use this, if the name of the projects corresponding to the route, then change the route to that page. But it didn't work and looks weird:

```
render() {
    const { route } = this.state;
    const projectName = projects.map(item => item.name);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { 
          route === 'home' ? (
            <div>
              <Dropdown routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <Home routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            </div>)
          : route === 'projects' ? (
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              <ProjectList projects={projects} routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            </div>)
          : route.includes(projectName) ? (
            <div>
              <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              {
                projects.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <Main name={projects[i].name} description={projects[i].description}/>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>)
         }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Can anybody help improve my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the code is working and you're just looking to improve the code quality then perhaps this question would be a little more on-topic on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for replying! This is my first time to ask a question on Stack Overflow and don't know codereview yet. I edited the description of my question to show the problem clearly. Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, but why "...I don't want to use React Router in this stage...", and can you clarify what you mean by "...I use the traditional way to do this..."? If you are "routing" around to different pages of your app why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to keep the way I used here because I learned it from my first React course. I called it the "traditional way" but maybe the "basic way" is more proper. I will use React Router in another project of mine for practicing both ways. And you're right, I think that .map() to render <Main /> is wrong here but I don't know how to modify it? Maybe .filter()? Still trying.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I think I should learn to create codesandbox to describe my problem next time. Thank you! I just found a way to modify my code from other suggestions. It works by using .filter(). Recording below for people who needs the help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to fix this.

Recording here for people who has the same questions like I was.

In App.js:

```
render() {
const { route } = this.state;
const routedProject = projects.filter(project => project.name === route)[0];

return (
  <div className="App">
    { 
      route === 'home' ? (
        <div>
          <Dropdown routeChange={this.onRouteChange} projects={projects}/>
          <Home routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        </div>)
      : route === 'about' ? (
        <div>
          <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} projects={projects}/>
          <About />
        </div>)
      : route === 'projects' ? (
        <div>
          <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} projects={projects}/>
          <ProjectList projects={projects} routeChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        </div>)
      : route === 'contact' ? (
        <div>
          <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} projects={projects}/>
          <Contact />
        </div>)
      : routedProject ? (
      < div >
          <Navigation routeChange={this.onRouteChange} projects={projects}/>
          <Main name={routedProject.name} description={routedProject.description} />
        </div>)
      : <div>404 Route Not Found</div>
    }
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

}

Thanks for all in Stack Overflow:)

Comment: If you just need to search an array then `.find` should be sufficient. `const routedProject = projects.find(project => project.name === route)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I can remove [0] in that way, it's even more concise and precise. Thanks a lot for your great comment!